# how to have the namespaces suggestions tool for visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I was watching some videos of C# on YouTube and I saw one where visual studio offered suggestions of namespaces when a property (which was not included in the used namespaces) was used,

I have looked for it on the internet, but the only nuggets that I have found are for Visual Studio Code, but not for **Visual Studio Community 2019**, I think it is what the guy in the video was using (he doesn't respond).

I took a screenshot of the suggestions,

[image: screenshot]

hope anyone can tell me how to download or activate it, because I have no clue.

Comment: This is called `IntelliSense`, I believe

Comment: try `ctrl + .`, but before that you need that library added to your project. as @PavelAnikhouski said it is an `IntelliSense`

Comment: Two steps.  First pick the IntelliSense suggestion, next click the lightbulb icon in the left rail or the red squiggles to let it add the missing *using* declaration.

Comment: That screenshot is taken from _JetBrains ReSharper_. https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Comment: @MickyD I just installed it, thank you for answering (:

Comment: You can trigger `IntelliSense` in any editor window by typing `Ctrl+Space` or by typing a trigger character. Read [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_intellisense-features) for more details.

Comment: @JaimeSantos you're welcome good sir.  Enjoy R# :)